# Way solving Segmentation fault

Tags: c

I made a C program solving below problem.

> Make a program that displays an English word of any number of characters entered from a keyboat in the opposite direction from normal. However, do not enter the number of characters in the English word, use variable length arrays or recurrence functions, or intentionally move the data to disk. For expamle; program → margorp"

However, when I input long string in this program,
the execution results expresses "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". Could you tell me how to solve it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  int i, len;
  char *str, *word, cp;
  
  printf("Input An English word > ");
  scanf("%s", word);
  len = strlen(word);

  printf("%d\n", len);
  
  str = (char *)malloc(len);
  strcpy(str, word);
    
  for(i=0; i<(len/2); i++) {
    cp = str[i];
    str[i] = str[len-i-1];
    str[len-i-1] = cp;
  }

  printf("%s\n", str);
  return 0;
}
```

**Execution results**

```
$ ./petest
Input An English word > abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
26
zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
$ ./petest
Input An English word > abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza
27
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$ ./petest
Input An English word > abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab
28
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$ ./petest
Input An English word > abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabc
29
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", word);` - there is no memory allocated for `word` and `word` points to undefined address.  That's why the program crashes.  A fash, yet not so robust solution, is to declare `word` as `char word[400];`  That should resolve your issue provided you don't type a word longer than 399 chars.

Comment: If your compiler did not warn you about using `word` without initializing it, you should turn up warning level. For GCC you can use `-Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: You just had bad luck to get something seemingly working with short words. If you were more lucky it had crashed immediately even with short words. That's the problem with undefined behaviour.

Comment: I would suggest using the `malloc()` and `realloc()` functions in `stdlib` to create a character buffer in memory and expand it when necessary (e.g., by doubling its size whenever it fills up). Since this is a homework question, I'll leave you to figure out the details.